# Networking Question - What is a VALID Subnet Address?

Tags: networking, ipv4, cisco, subnet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does IPv4 Subnetting Work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work)

I am currently revising Networking for the Cisco CCNA1. One of the questions that I am struggling to answer is the following:

Which of the following IPv4 addresses are vaild subnet addresses:

- 172.16.4.127 /26
- 172.16.4.155 /26
- 172.16.4.193 /26
- 172.16.4.95  /27
- 172.16.4.159 /27
- 127.16.4.207 /27

I can't get my head around how to know understand when a subnet address is valid or not.

Many thanks

Answer (score 8):

IP addresses are 32-bits long, the mask is also 32 bits.  When you perform a logical `AND` of the address and the mask, you get the subnet address.  See this wikipedia section on how to [determine the network prefix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork#Determining_the_network_prefix).

My mental shortcut that works for netmasks >= 25 is I subtract the mask length from 32 and look at the last octet of the IP address... that is the maximum host bits in the address (call that number `h`).  If the last octet is evenly divisible by `2**h`, then that is a subnet address.

For example, 172.16.4.127/26... `32 - 26 = 6`.  `2**6 = 64` and `127 % 64 = 63`.  Therefore, 172.16.4.127 is *not* a valid subnet address... in fact it is the broadcast address for the 172.16.4.64/26 subnet.  Good luck with your CCNA exam.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is either *all*, or *none* depending on what they mean.

The *normal* understanding of a 'valid' subnet address is one in which the address quoted is the lowest possible in the specified range.  Hence a /26 (64 addresses) would end with a multiple of 64, and a /27 would end with a multiple of 32.

None of the addresses you've quoted meet that rule.

- 172.16.4.127 /26  -  this is the *broadcast address* for 172.16.4.64 /26
- 172.16.4.155 /26  -  this sits in the range 172.16.4.128 - 191
- 172.16.4.193 /26  -  this is the first *usable* address in 172.16.4.192 /26
- 172.16.4.95 /27   -  this is the *broadcast address* for 172.16.4.64 /27
- 172.16.4.159 /27  -  this is the *broadcast address* for 172.16.4.128 /27
- 127.16.4.207 /27  -  this sits in the range 172.16.4.192 - 223

Are you sure you copied them correctly?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I'm parsing your answer... you say it could be all or none depending on what they mean... 172.16.4.127/26 is not a valid subnet address...  That is the broadcast address, by definition.  He is studying for a test, and they throw these kind of problems at them to ensure they understand the concepts correctly.

Comment: what I'm saying is that none of the supplied values match the _usual_ definition of a "subnet address".

Comment: @ Mike Pennington - "to ensure they understand" I find CCNA very difficult, I can pass 90% of the exams, and I can subnet successfull, but I dont understand theses sorts of questions. So for instance 172.16.4.127/26 is the last address before the next subnet meaning that it is a broadcast address, this means that it is not a useable address by a host therefore not a subnet address.Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

When I get lost with network addresses (I agree, it is not easy to calculate those /26 or /27s), I just ask the [ipcalc tool](http://jodies.de/ipcalc) to do the math for me. But be careful, because `ipcalc` in CentOS/RHEL is a completely different tool.

You run [`ipcalc`](http://jodies.de/ipcalc) and pass it some kind of network address as an argument and it gives you all kinds of useful self-explanatory information (looking at the binary netmask you can understand what a valid network address is in such a way that you will remember it). Taking your first address as an example (the space before the slash is optional).

```
$ ipcalc 172.16.4.127 /26
Address:   172.16.4.127         10101100.00010000.00000100.01 111111
Netmask:   255.255.255.192 = 26 11111111.11111111.11111111.11 000000
Wildcard:  0.0.0.63             00000000.00000000.00000000.00 111111
=>
Network:   172.16.4.64/26       10101100.00010000.00000100.01 000000
HostMin:   172.16.4.65          10101100.00010000.00000100.01 000001
HostMax:   172.16.4.126         10101100.00010000.00000100.01 111110
Broadcast: 172.16.4.127         10101100.00010000.00000100.01 111111
Hosts/Net: 62                    Class B, Private Internet
```

So in your case, 172.16.4.127 is the broadcast for the 172.16.4.64/26 network. And for a complete answer:

- 172.16.4.127/26

  - Network:   172.16.4.64/26
  - Broadcast: 172.16.4.127
- 172.16.4.155/26

  - Network:   172.16.4.128/26
- 172.16.4.193/26

  - Network:   172.16.4.192/26
  - HostMin:   172.16.4.193
- 172.16.4.95/27

  - Network:   172.16.4.64/27
  - Broadcast: 172.16.4.95
- 172.16.4.159/27

  - Network:   172.16.4.128/27
  - Broadcast: 172.16.4.159
- 172.16.4.207/27

  - Network:   172.16.4.192/27

Answer (score 1):

- A is the broadcast address for the subnet "10"
- B is a valid address for the subnet "10" which is a valid subnet.
- C is a valid address for the subnet "11" which is considered to be an invalid subnet
- D is the broadcast address for the subnet "101"
- E is a valid address for the subnet "110" whcih is a valid subnet.

I see this way: B and E are valid IP address and I think it's what they mean as "IPv4 addresses are vaild subnet addresses" although the question in the way it's put is likelly to cause misunderstanding.